# JavaScript Regex Compile()

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a shorter way to write this?

```
var needed = /\$\[\w+\]/mi;
needed.compile(/\$\[\w+\]/mi);
```

Why do I have to pass the pattern back into the regex when I've already declared it in the first line?!

Comment: If I don't include the pattern again, the regex takes about twice as long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways of defining regular expressions in JavaScript — one through an object constructor and one through a literal. The object can be changed at runtime, but the literal is compiled at load of the script, and provides better performance.

```
var txt=new RegExp(pattern,modifiers);
```

or more simply:

```
var txt=/pattern/modifiers;
```

This is the same thing that cobbai is saying. In short, you do not have to do both.

Answer (score 2):

from [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/RegExp):

> The literal notation provides compilation of the regular expression when the expression is evaluated

so `/\$\[\w+\]/mi` is a compiled regex already.